# Crawling Google Play Store Apps

Tags: android, python-3.x, google-play, web-crawler

I want to crawl the google play store and get all the app ids of a particular category. When I executed the below code I just got the app ids of first 49 apps not more than that. But I want to get all the app ids. How can I achieve this? 
And the URL that I used was https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sports&c=apps&hl=en for scrapping.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url=input('Enter:')
html=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

tags=soup('a')
l=list()
for tag in tags:
    x=tag.get('href',None)
    if x.find("/store/apps/details?id=")!=-1:
       if not(x[23:] in l):
            l.append(x[23:])
print(l)
```

Comment: I don't know where you're scraping from but 50 is such a peculiar number that it's very likely that you are only scraping page 1 of many

Comment: I am scraping the app ids in the first if condition and then storing the app id in a list. Yes, I suppose that it is scrapping only page 1 of many. How to scrap all the pages?

Comment: After 48 or 49 first apps the following batch of apps change their class/Ids.